How to consume docker image saved as artifact in Azure Pipeline from previous job/stage
In Azure Pipeline, how do I load image directly for job in subsequence stage as container?
Eg. saved image from previous stage
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/saved-image.tar'
      ArtifactName: 'saved-image'

Subsequence stage
        - job: SomeJob
          container: saved-image ??

Is it even possible? If not, what're some of the alternatives especially if I would like to use that image to spin up parallel jobs?
Goal: Able to consume saved image to later jobs / jobs directly in different stage without additional agent.

As mentioned in my answer below, To use your custom Docker image to set up container jobs, you need to push the Docker image to a container repository, and then set a container resource in your YAML pipeline to reference the Docker image from the container registry. @xtremeHitori

What strategy would you recommend if I can pull container image from ACR but the problem is these jobs need the same prerequsite steps like installing dependencies and running prep work.
How do I DRY those steps and increase efficiency with sharing workspace?

You can try to execute these common steps via command lines when building the Docker image with the Dockerfile. @xtremeHitori

In Azure Pipelines, the container job is letting you to run all steps of a job within the environment of a container. The steps can use the resources has been set up when building the Docker image. the steps also can set up more other resources if requited every time. If some resources are commonly requited, you can try to set some command lines in the Dockerfile to set up these you can set up resources.Then when building the Docker image with the Dockerfile, these resources will be preinstalled in the environment of the container.  @xtremeHitori

It is not possible to using the Docker image which is published as a pipeline artifact from a previous job to set container jobs. Because the Docker image need to be downloaded and the container need to be started before the jobs start.
You need to first push the Docker image to a repository (public or private) on the container registry (such as Docker Hub, Azure Container Registry, etc..), then set a container resource in your YAML pipeline to reference the Docker image from the container registry.
When running the pipeline container job, the system will pull the image from the  container registry and start the container, then start the job to run in the container.
For more details, see "Define container jobs".
